# win32api.keybd_event stopped working

Tags: python, winapi, events, keyboard

These two lines of code used to work (sending a keyboard event of the letter a to the currently focused window).
They stopped working recently, i'm guessing since some windows update.

```
import win32api
win32api.keybd_event(0, win32api.MapVirtualKey(66, 0), 0, 0)
```

Is it a known bug/issue and is there some workaround?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

keydb_event is unreliable instead use SendInput function